# Поиск url в тексте и превращение его в <a>

Tags: php, ссылки, текст

Есть вот такой код, он работает, но если есть `<br />`, то к url прибавляются частички от `<br />`

```
$new_text = preg_replace("~(http|https|ftp|ftps)://(.*?)(\s|\n|[,.?!](\s|\n)|$)~", '<a href="$1://$2">$1://$2</a>$3', $text);
return $new_text;
```

Например, ссылка https://www.google.com/
Если она написана в тексте вот так

> https://www.google.com/

То все работает.

Если она написана в тексте вот так

> Найти в Google - https://www.google.com/ Сайт Google

То все работает.

Если она написана в тексте вот так

> Найти в Google  https://www.google.com/`<br/>`
> Загуглить

То ссылка поглощает частички 
 и все что идет после нею.

**Как это исправить? И возможно ли сделать переадресацию с ссылки на определенную страницу, чтобы проверить допустим ли этот домен для перехода и т. д.**

*Желательно с объяснением.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте ограничение на угловые скобки *(и пробелы)*:

```
$text = 'Найти в Google https://www.google.com/<br/>Загуглить';

$patt = '~(?:https?|ftps?)://[^<>\s]+~';
$repl = '<a href="$0">$0</a>';
$newText = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $text);

echo $newText;
```

Результат:

```
Найти в Google <a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a><br/>Загуглить
```